# Inside the loop, write a line of code that populates the matrix M with the numbers 1 through 20

Tags: r

I keep ending up with a matrix populated entirely by 20s. It is iterating over the number and through the indices of the matrix M but it is over writing it each time when I am looking for a matrix that is 10x2 with only unique values.

```
n = 20; 
M = matrix(NA, ncol = 2, nrow = 10);
a = 1
b = 1
for (i in 1:n){
    for (r in 1:nrow(M))   
        for (c in 1:ncol(M))
        i -> M[r,c]
        print(M)
}
M
```

Comment: Nothing is ever either `==` or `!=` to NA. Learn to use `is.na()` for logical tests for missingness.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is your desired outcome? Also, what does `a` and `b` do? I would also not recommend assigning `c` a value as it is good practice not to assign values to established functions in R

Comment: I am looking for a Matrix 10 x 2 populated 1 to 20 in order from M[1,1] to M[20, 2]

Comment: Sure but I'm confused why you cant do `matrix(1:20, ncol = 2)`

Comment: It just an exercise, I am new to R and trying to learn

Comment: Gotcha - if you do `matrix(1:20, ncol = 2)` that should do what you want

Comment: You're looping over every value in `1:n`, then inside that loop, looping over every row/column combination and writing `i` as each value. So that last loop through will always be `20`, and it will be written as every row/column.

Comment: @thelatemail should I include an if statement in the last loop to check if the index spot has been populated to stop the for loop?

Comment: @svin24 If you are indexing by a variable that ends at 20 then no test is needed because that will terminate the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that if the outer for-loop is indexed by increasing values to be entered as elements  into the matrix, that the value of `i` should be used to decide which position it goes to. (If the values were not sequential then you could use the result of `seq_along( your_non_consecutive_variable)` as the index for the loop and the way to pick the value to be entered into the matrix. You CANNOT work with a single value set at the outer loop, and then repeat an assignment of that value multiple times with two nested inner loops.

```
n = 20; 
M = matrix(NA, ncol = 2, nrow = 10);
a = 1
b = 1
for (i in 1:n){
    if( i <= 10){ M[i, 1] <- i} else
        { M[i-10, 2] <- i}} 
M
#---------
     [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1   11
 [2,]    2   12
 [3,]    3   13
 [4,]    4   14
 [5,]    5   15
 [6,]    6   16
 [7,]    7   17
 [8,]    8   18
 [9,]    9   19
[10,]   10   20
```

That said this is only to be used as an exercise in understanding for-loops. A more R-ish way of putting values into a matrix would be:

```
var <- sample(1:20)
M <- matrix( var, 2, 10)
```

The values in `var` get assigned to rows 1:10 in the first column and then rows 1:10 in the second column. R handles its matrix indexing in a column major fashion. This is important to understand when working with the results of `sapply` operations.